# AWS IoT Java SDK - broker disconnects after message publish

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

There is an established connection to the IoT broker endpoint through the Java SDK, I can see 3 related threads in the JVM: MQTT Rec:, MQTT Snd: and MQTT Call.
As I call client.publish(...) using the AWSIotMqttClient, the client immediately disconnects from the broker with the following log messages:

***May 16, 2020 12:15:52 AM com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection onConnectionFailure
INFO: Connection temporarily lost***

The disconnection reason (captured by a presence change event with Lambda): ***CONNECTION_LOST***

I'm establishing connection in an init method as follows:

```
public void init() {
  client = new AWSIotMqttClient(MQTT_CLIENT_ENDPOINT, MQTT_CLIENT_ID + new BigInteger(64, new SecureRandom()).toString(32), readStore(), KEYPASS);
  client.setPort(8883);

  try {
    client.connect(5000, false);

  } catch (AWSIotException e) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The connection is successfully established.

I'm trying to publish in a different method (running as a webservice endpoint code, in another thread):

```
try {
  AWSIotMessage message = new AWSIotMessage(topic, AWSIotQos.QOS0, commandString);
  client.publish(message, 3000);
} catch (AWSIotException e) {
  ...
}
```

The `commandString` is published to the topic, however the MQTT connection immediately disconnects and reconnects.

Here is the policy attached to the certificate:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The topic I want to publish: 'topictest'

Please advise.

Comment: Possibly a permissions issue - include the topic you are publishing on and the policy attached to the client's certificate in your question.

This might also be relevant: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/issues/21

Comment: I checked that issue report for the SDK and found that it was caused by a different root cause (more connection instances were competing with each other). In my case the connection is stable for a long time, up until the point when a publish occurs, when it just disconnects after the message was sent. I will check the permissions, that may be a good lead.